# How quickly can we do an inverse discrete Fourier transform over any commutative ring with unity, EXACTLY?

Tags: ring-theory, algorithms, fourier-analysis

If we assume that we're doing a size $n$ (inverse) DFT, I'm simply trying to ensure that we can do it faster than "exponential" time...  In other words, say in time $o(2^n)$.  However, this should work over any commutative ring with unity.  Also, if possible, we should be able to calculate this exactly.

I'm a little unsure of how to go about this...  I believe that the DFT matrices (calculations, for example in FFT) are supposed to be numerically stable, so maybe we can use approximations.  I've found [this paper on worst-case FFTs](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniel-Potts-4/publication/228928313_Numerical_stability_of_fast_trigonometric_transforms-a_worst_case_study/links/0c960537cf31b8350e000000/Numerical-stability-of-fast-trigonometric-transforms-a-worst-case-study.pdf).  Then there's [this paper on DFTs in arbitrary rings](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Eric-Dubois-6/publication/3047154_The_Discrete_Fourier_Transform_Over_Finite_Rings_with_Application_to_Fast_Convolution/links/58208a7c08ae40da2cb4ec65/The-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-Over-Finite-Rings-with-Application-to-Fast-Convolution.pdf).

I really don't understand how to even do the transform with some rings.  Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.  If this is a hard question to solve, perhaps someone could simply suggest what I should study.

Comment: How is a Discrete Fourier Tranfoem defined in an arbitrary commutative ring with identity?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  I'm not sure.  It should be defined in the paper on arbitrary rings...  They talk about local rings and group rings, I believe...  I didn't understand them, so I'm looking for someone who either knows how to solve the original question, or someone who can point out where to get the necessary background on these topics.  The links are to ResearchGate, so you should be able to download the papers.

Comment: Ah, okay, $R$ a ring and $G$ a finite abelian group or order $n$, then that paper says that a DFT is an isomorphism from the group ring $R[G]$ with the product ring $R^n.$ So the DFT is not really defined on the ring $R$ but the ring $R[G].$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  Yes.  I didn't really understand that terminology, along with the diagram in the paper.  So right now the question is if this can be done with the required speed, and if it can, what would I need to study to understand it.  So far I've read about 2/3 of Charles Pinter's "Abstract Algebra", but I guess I'm a bit shaky with it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Rereading you comment, I now wonder how hard it is to transform $R$ into $R[G]$.  I've tried studying Wikipedia, but I think I may need more background material.  Could you recommend what I should study?  Like more abstract algebra, or is there something else I may need?